# MVC 5 View calling JavaScript causing error?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm not really sure why this is not working but I have an MVC View that I want to display the current date/time/seconds on the page. I've put the javascript in the "Scripts/script.js" file. I then added the following at the bottom of the MVC View.

```
@section scripts {

    <script src="~/Scripts/script.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            setDateTimer();
        });

    </script>

}
```

Thing is when I run it something is causing an error. Unfortunately at the moment I can't see the actual error message because of the way they have the site configured any error just takes you to a generic error page. I do know it has something to do with the code above because removing it cause the page to work.

For testing purposes I even removed all but simple javascript code in the file but that still doesn't work. Right now this is all that is in my script.js file.

```
function setDateTimer() {
    var today = new Date();
}
```

I know the name of the of the .js file in the code is correct because I just dragged and dropped it to the page from the solution explorer.

Here is most of my _Layout page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
            <footer></footer>
        </div>

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error? can you post your `_Layout` page?

Comment: I can't see the actual error right now because of the way the site is setup to send you to a generic error page. I striped out some stuff out of the Layout page and posted it but. All the relevant stuff is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout page doesn't have a place to render the section you can change it like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
            <footer></footer>
        </div>

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
     @RenderSection("scripts",true)
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what was missing.